# Mark up ASP.net validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, servercontrols

I have created a simple webform using the designer in ASP.net (Vs2013). The system really works well, I only had to use a few textboxes and custom validation controls from the Toolbox. The form checks client sided if the input is correct and shows an error message if not.

However the errormessage just gets shown on the page in ugly red text atm. I would very much like to mark-up this error message, for example use the Jquery fade-in function on the error or use any custom javascript to hook in this emited js from ASP.

What and where would be the best way to do this?

code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="registreren.aspx.cs" Inherits="registreren" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script> 

    <title></title>
    <link href="WebsiteStyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="height: 244px">

        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2" rowspan="1">Username</td>
                <td class="auto-style7" rowspan="1">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxUsername" runat="server" Width="240px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td rowspan="1">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredUsername" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxUsername" ErrorMessage="Please enter an username." CssClass="validationError"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3" rowspan="1">Email</td>
                <td class="auto-style6" rowspan="1">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEmail" runat="server" Width="240px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style4" rowspan="1">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail" ErrorMessage="Please enter your emailaddress." CssClass="validationError"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2" rowspan="1">Password</td>
                <td class="auto-style7" rowspan="1">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxPassword" runat="server" Width="240px" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td rowspan="1">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredPassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxPassword" ErrorMessage="Please enter a password." CssClass="validationError"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2" rowspan="1">Confirm Password</td>
                <td class="auto-style7" rowspan="1">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxConfirmPassword" runat="server" Width="240px" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td rowspan="1">

                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="RequiredConfirmPassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxConfirmPassword" ErrorMessage="Please confirm the password." ClientValidationFunction="validateConfirmPassword" ValidateEmptyText="True" CssClass="validationError"></asp:CustomValidator>

                        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2" rowspan="1">Country</td>
                <td class="auto-style7" rowspan="1">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListSelectCountry" runat="server" Height="16px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="240px">
                        <asp:ListItem>Select country</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>The Netherlands</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Belgium</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>France</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Germany</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td rowspan="1">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredCountry" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownListSelectCountry" ErrorMessage="Please select a country." InitialValue="Select country" CssClass="validationError"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2" rowspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style7" rowspan="1">
                    <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                </td>
                <td rowspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
    </form>

         <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/customScripts.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? It also might be better if you posted the generated HTML.

Comment: Yes I have tried making a custom validator where you can use JS logic to validate your own form. And in this JS logic I tried the Jquery.fadeIn() on the errormessage class. However what happeneds is that ASP first fires the code to make the error message visible on HTML before it reaches the fadeIn code which results in a blinking error message before it fades in, which cant be best practise if you ask me.